# Ruby but not Rails on my Resume

Tags: resume, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have listed Ruby as a skill on my resume becuase I've been programming in Ruby for 5 years while I work on my Ph.D. thesis. I've mostly been using it to implement natural language processing algorithms.

I'm starting to look for a job, and I posted my resume to a few sites (as an extra bonus when applying to certain on-target jobs). Now I get recruiters calling me to offer me Ruby on Rails jobs. The problem is that I've never learned Rails. It was never relevant to what I'm doing for my Ph.D.

How do you recommend handling this situation to avoid wasting my time and theirs? (And learning Rails probably isn't an option until I finish my thesis.) Can my resume be adjusted to make this clearer? Should it be adjusted? Should I just politely tell them on the phone that I don't know Rails?

By the way, the relevant part of my resume simply says:

> ### Skills:
>
> **Programming Languages:**  C, C++, Java, Scala, Ruby, LaTeX
>
> **Databases:** MySQL, XML, XPath

and lists a few other skill areas that couldn't possibly be confused with a Rails developer.

Comment: +1 for bringing up a problem that will be faced by anyone with Ruby on his or her resume. This is a very common phenomenon.

Comment: XML counts as a database now?

Comment: Don't take it personally, recruiters are playing a numbers game.  They get paid for successful matches, so the job market is like an intellectual meat market.  If you match their search they will offer the job.  That's all they can do.

Comment: @Slokun: where would you put it? Particularly when what I've been doing is reading linguistic annotations in various standoff XML formats and using XPath to convert them into internal representations that I can work with. Maybe it belongs in the languages section?

Comment: @Ken Been a few months since I last looked at my resume, but pretty sure I have it under either technologies or languages. Also, meant to put a ":P" at the end, guess I forgot.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: Languages would do in a pinch, but I usually add a third category for "Technologies" that aren't really languages or databases. Frameworks and things like XML typically land in there for me.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: You could add XML and XPath to "Langauges" if you rename "Languages" to "Technologies". Then you could optionally add MySQL to "TechnologieS" if it looks too lonely all by itself in "Databases".

Comment: @Slokun, XML is a perfect example of a semistructured database. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-structured_model

Comment: Add a skill of hurting headhunter who can't read resume

Comment: isnt latex a markup language rather than a programming language?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a good question.

I would leave your resume alone. It's good to filter out languages you are not comfortable working with, but do not filter out frameworks. You don't know what version of your resume will be sitting on someone's desk when they become interested in you. By the time they see it, you might be a well-versed Rails developer.

With that, I would much rather have a dozen calls about Rails opportunities just to have *one* turn out to be plain Ruby. Recruiters tend to think `ruby == rails` so don't confuse them.

Comment: So, then I suppose I should be asking the recruiter a couple of quick questions to verify whether the job is a web development job (presumably requiring Rails) versus some other job (where the recruiter has confused Ruby with Rails)?

Comment: @Ken: Yes. A lot of recruiters are calling you based on a set of vague (to us) criteria. I like it when I am able to control how opportunities are filtered instead of someone else deciding for me.

Comment: +1 for leaving an opening for the plain Ruby opportunity

Answer (score 28):

You could tell them you're very good with Ruby (assuming you ARE good with Ruby) and that you'd be willing to learn Rails as a part of a new job (assuming you ARE willing and interested to learn the Rails framework). On-the-job training is not that uncommon. I had to pick up JavaEE, Spring, Hibernate on the job. I had Java and web apps (not in Java) so they figured I could adapt.

In general, don't put negatives on a resume such as "Ruby but NOT Ruby on Rails", it just doesn't look good.

Answer (score 12):

To a recruiter **ruby = rails**.  It's not right, and it's a very narrow view of the Ruby world, but that's how a recruiter processes buzzwords.  It would be like equating Django with Python, but the majority of the demand for Ruby jobs is for Rails applications.  It will take time and *another* killer app to make that distinction.

Comment: ...or ruby == rails...

Comment: No, they've redefined ruby in their minds.  They've fallen prey to that assignment vs. equality operator error.

Comment: that or you're writing in Pascal.

Comment: Nice escape...however you then go on to mention equating...not assignment in a few sentences down the road.

Comment: :P  Doh!  You're too quick...

Answer (score 4):

Nothing that you do on your resume will stop 90% of recruiters from contacting you about Rails jobs. Just develop a thick skin and cultivate patience.

Comment: +1, even with no mention of Ruby they will ask you for whatever they are currently looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby with no rails? -10 to being fashionable :)

Put "willing to learn rails", better than 'no rails' :)

Answer (score 1):

I would leave it as is and just list Ruby.

I would also spend 1 hour boning up and if you know Ruby well, there's not that much to know.

- It's Model-View-Controller.
- The models represent database tables through the rails ORM, mapping models and attributes to tables.
- Functionality such as authentication can be done through 'gems'.
- html is created through 'ERB' templates.
- Low cost hosting solutions exist, e.g. Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Recruiters who are calling are tytpically first level screeners. They make calls on a daily basis. Think of them as salesmen. Telling them no means you might be interested. In addition if they are not at a technical scale Ruby and Rails may be synonymous to them.

Tell them politely when they call that you are not familiar with Rails and would prefer to focus in a Ruby only environment; the portion of your resume you listed looks adequate and I would not suggest changing it based on the current issue.

Answer (score -2):

#### Clarify

You could clarify that you don't have Rails experience by putting *"not Rails"* at the end. That is if you really don't want any Rails jobs. This has the downside of automatically limiting your options as it indicated you don't know, and have no interest in learning Rails.

#### Learn

Why not learn Rails? If you really know Ruby well, Rails should be easy. Then you can say Ruby / Rails and open yourself up to more opportunities.

Comment: I would advise against putting negatives in a resume.

Comment: Would love for someone to explain the downvote.

Comment: @Frustrated: That was listed as one possible option.

Comment: @Josh The OP has already stated in his question that learning Rails isn't an option right now. He also never said that he had no interest, just that it's not relevant to his thesis. Going to guess that's why the downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote. So far, I'm just sitting back and reading the answers. I don't mind learning Rails in the future, but for now it will distract from time I need to spend finishing my thesis.

Comment: @Slokun: In that case he should just reply "No" to recruiters. My resume lists PHP / Java / Grails / Python / Django and I *still* get people asking me to do Rails work. I have no mention of Ruby on there.

Comment: @Josh K: Heh, they probably think Grails is like Rails - they sound similar, at least.

Comment: @Frustrated: Actually was doing a project in Grails at the same time someone else was doing on in Rails. We ended up having to call them "G" and "R" because it was getting so confusing.